# Rails 5: stuck in Edit action, Update not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controllers

I'm stuck with kind of simple thing where I've tried a lot of things which don't work. Here is what I have. 
In my app current_user needs to update roles for users, who belong to current_user companies. I can get to Edit action, where appropriate selects for particular user role is shown, however **I cannot do Update action - it always stay in Edit action**.

This is what I have in */models/role.rb*:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user, optional: true, inverse_of: :roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
# other columns for roles follow #
```

*/models/user.rb* looks like this:

```
#User has roles
  has_many :roles
  has_many :company_user_roles, through: :companies, source: :user_roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }

# User has many companies
  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :accounts
```

In */controllers/common/roles_controller.rb* I have this:

```
class Common::RolesController < ApplicationController

def edit
@role = Role.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@role = Role.find(params[:id])
if @role.update_attributes(role_params)
  flash[:success] = "Role updated!"
  redirect_to dashboard_path
else
  render 'edit'
end

private

def role_params #at the end ID of user to whom belongs role is stored
  params.require(:role).permit(:general, :dashboard, //..other role table columns..// , :user_id)
end
```

In */views/common/roles/edit.html.erb* I have this:

```
<%= form_for ([:common, @role]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :general, Role.generals.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] } %>
  <%= f.select :dashboard, Role.dashboards.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] } %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

When I open */common/roles/1/edit* I see this:

```
Started GET "/common/roles/1/edit" for 194.8.16.19 at 2016-10-17 13:08:17 +0000
Processing by Common::RolesController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

When I press on "Save changes" button, I see this:

```
Started GET "/common/roles/1/edit?utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=patch&authenticity_token=QoCCvXkM2%2B77ZyO0npTBKv1PKTQdkFjkLLbIgmdSXN8uli1ElLBfwHD6GXVTA%2Fa65cQPVPCqJNSkF0d8l5SSgw%3D%3D&general=seller_buyer&dashboard=editer&rights=editer&commit=Save+changes" for 194.8.16.19 at 2016-10-17 13:10:54 +0000
Processing by Common::RolesController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QoCCvXkM2+77ZyO0npTBKv1PKTQdkFjkLLbIgmdSXN8uli1ElLBfwHD6GXVTA/a65cQPVPCqJNSkF0d8l5SSgw==", "general"=>"seller_buyer", "dashboard"=>"editer", "rights"=>"editer", "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

or like this:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  _method: patch
  authenticity_token: QoCCvXkM2+77ZyO0npTBKv1PKTQdkFjkLLbIgmdSXN8uli1ElLBfwHD6GXVTA/a65cQPVPCqJNSkF0d8l5SSgw==
  general: seller_buyer
  dashboard: editer
  rights: editer
  commit: Save changes
  controller: common/roles
  action: edit
  id: '1'
permitted: false
```

**Looks like it is not passing "role"=> {...** and after token it shows params which I try to update. As I understand this could be, why Update is not happening.

role *routes.rb* look like this:

```
 namespace :common do
   resources :companies
   resources :roles
 end
```

Index and Edit action for roles work, all actions, including Update, work for companies.

I'm a bit desperate regarding this error, as I have tried a lot of things, however nothing works. **How can I fix this to make Update action work, please?** Thank you for any hint where potential error could be.

**Update**
I can update roles manually in console with no problem - find role by ID and update any column. Still no luck in form - stays in Edit action after `f.submit`.

**Update 2**

Seems like everything with routes are good:

```
                     common_roles GET    /common/roles(.:format)                          common/roles#index
                                  POST   /common/roles(.:format)                          common/roles#create
                  new_common_role GET    /common/roles/new(.:format)                      common/roles#new
                 edit_common_role GET    /common/roles/:id/edit(.:format)                 common/roles#edit
                      common_role GET    /common/roles/:id(.:format)                      common/roles#show
                                  PATCH  /common/roles/:id(.:format)                      common/roles#update
                                  PUT    /common/roles/:id(.:format)                      common/roles#update
                                  DELETE /common/roles/:id(.:format)                      common/roles#destroy
```

So far no idea why error is still happening... as I understand it is not because of wrong routes.

**Update 3**

Ok, I have figured out, why Edit action stuck - because I thought it does not matter if `form_for` is before or after `<form class>` tag. It appears to be that I had to put it BEFORE `<form class>` tag. So no now I get the main error out on screent: `param is missing or the value is empty: role` **Any ideas why?**

**Update 4**

Ok, so now I have found out the main problem. Basically Enums are not updating at all. Since my form consists of Enums only, it is not passed and not updated. Now I have to find out, how I have to save/update Enums correctly. Any hint is welcomed!

Comment: The issue is the method: `form_for` should generate a form with a POST method (you should see "Started POST on [...]" when clicking "Save changes")

Comment: @user3033467 Yes, I know, however I have identical form_for "Companies" (e.g., /common/companies/1/edit) and there I can do Update without any problems. This is confusing me a lot. How do I get to POST then, please?

Comment: You should not be using spaces between your method names and their opening parenthesis. `form_for (` should be `form_for(`.

Comment: @meagar, ok, changed, but error same. I tried user3033467 solution, but nothing changed - same old error I have had :(

Answer (score 0):

`form_for ([:common, @role], :html => { method: 'POST' })` should work

Comment: It gave me this error: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input` although I have put ` <% end %>` at the end of my form.

Comment: however no change - still stuck in Edit action

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.